# OpenDJ release/3.0.0 compile error

Tags: opendj

It's really odd that I downloaded the source code from Forgerock's stash repo to my linux local, but it always complain an compile error for the ant  stuff . Below is the detailed error msg. Any idea why ?

```
generateadmin:
     [exec] 
     [exec] BUILD FAILED
     [exec] /home/xifeng/Downloads/new_test/3rd/opendj/release-3.0.0/opendj/opendj-server-legacy/build.xml:99: Fatal error during transformation using /home/xifeng/Downloads/new_test/3rd/opendj/release-3.0.0/opendj/opendj-server-legacy/resource/admin/metaMO.xsl: Cannot find external method 'java.io.File.toURI' (must be public).


[INFO] OpenDJ ............................................. FAILURE [ 31.211 s]
[INFO] OpenDJ DSML Gateway ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (generate-config) on project opendj-server-legacy: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /home/xifeng/Downloads/new_test/3rd/opendj/release-3.0.0/opendj/opendj-server-legacy/build.xml:76: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="/home/xifeng/Downloads/new_test/3rd/opendj/release-3.0.0/opendj/opendj-server-legacy/build.xml">... @ 4:113 in /home/xifeng/Downloads/new_test/3rd/opendj/release-3.0.0/opendj/opendj-server-legacy/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood the cause.

In my `opendj/.gitignore` file, I have:

```
# Package Files #
*.jar
```

meaning that when I submit those archives to my own git repo, they aren't committed.

Thus, when someone else clones my repo they will fail to compile.